# easiest way to know when a MySQL database was last accessed

Tags: mysql, innodb, audit, information-schema

I have MySQL tables that are all InnoDB.

We have so many copies of various databases spread across multiple servers (trust me we're talking hundreds here), and many of them are not being queried at all.

How can I get a list of the MAX(LastAccessDate) for example for all tables within a specific database?  Esp. considering that they are InnoDB tables.

I would prefer knowing even where the "select" query was run, but would settle for "insert/update" as well, since, if a db hasn't changed in a long time, it's probably dead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table that always gets values inserted you can add a trigger to the update/insert. Inside this trigger you can set the current timestamp in a dedicated database, including the name of the database from which the insert took place.

This way the only requirement of your database is that it supports triggers.

Alternatively you could take a look this [link](http://sqlandme.com/2014/03/11/sql-server-how-to-get-last-accessupdate-time-for-a-table/):

odify date and create date for a table can be retrieved from sys.tables catalog view. When any structural changes are made the modify date is updated. It can be queried as follows:

```
USE [SqlAndMe]
GO

SELECT    [TableName] = name,
create_date,
modify_date
FROM    sys.tables
WHERE    name = 'TransactionHistoryArchive'
GO
```

sys.tables only shows modify date for structural changes. If we need to check when was the tables last updated or accessed, we can use dynamic management view sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats. This DMV returns counts of different types of index operations and last time the operation was performed.

It can be used as follows:

```
USE [SqlAndMe]
GO

SELECT    [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
last_user_update, last_user_seek, last_user_scan, last_user_lookup
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE    database_id = DB_ID('SqlAndMe')
AND        OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'TransactionHistoryArchive'
GO
```

last_user_update – provides time of last user update

last_user_* – provides time of last scan/seek/lookup

It is important to note that sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats counters are reset when SQL Server service is restarted.

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Those examples are for Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.